# Input type date ,time not working on other browsers except Chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, google-chrome

Input type date or time not working firefox or other browsers except crome.
Is there any way to use input type date or time in other browsers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's known issue for fire fox check out this [HTML5 input types, many have yet to be implemented in both firefox](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=825294)

If the browser does not support the HTML5 features you want to use, try [Modernizr](http://modernizr.com/). It uses *Javascript* to enhance support. It's documentation has information about [input types](http://modernizr.com/docs/#inputtypes).

Answer (score 1):

You can use the jQuery UI Datepicker. http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/. It supports the major browsers.

Comment: there is any way to use html5 elements for date and time in browsers like firefox. beacuse i have a project that have many html 5 elements, i dont want to modify all stuff.